# XGBoost and cross-validation in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I see that both `XGBClassifier()` and `sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV()` have the parameter `n_jobs`. I performed CV and I saw that by setting `n_jobs = -1` (in both) I made use of the 16 workers I had:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 30 candidates, totalling 150 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 16 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 tasks      | elapsed: 13.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  18 tasks      | elapsed: 20.4min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  29 tasks      | elapsed: 23.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  40 tasks      | elapsed: 28.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  53 tasks      | elapsed: 36.1min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  66 tasks      | elapsed: 43.4min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  81 tasks      | elapsed: 47.6min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  96 tasks      | elapsed: 50.8min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 113 tasks      | elapsed: 60.0min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 135 out of 150 | elapsed: 73.1min remaining: 8.1min
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 150 out of 150 | elapsed: 85.7min finished
```

I cannot repeat the analysis now, but I assume the parallelization occurred because of the `n_jobs=1` in `RandomizedSearchCV()`.

I know very little on parallel computing. I understand that `RandomizedSearchCV()` runs each parameters setting independently, but how does it work in concrete when parallelizing? And what about the `n_jobs=-1` en `XGBClassifier()`? Does it make sense to set this parameter in both functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Q: Does it make sense to set this parameter in both functions?

A short version: No, it does not.

A longer version will need to take a bit of understanding, how the **`n_jobs`** are actually being handled.

Having a few, expensive, resources ( right, the CPU-cores per se, the fastest and the most expensive CPU-core-local Cache hierarchy elements ( not going as deep to study cache-lines and their respective associativity at this level ) and the less expensive and also way slower RAM-memory ), the **`n_jobs = -1`** directive, in the first call-signature executed, will simply grab all these resources at once.

That means, there will be no reasonably "free" resources for any "deeper" levels of attempt to use -again- "as many resources" as physically available ( which the **`n_jobs = -1`** does and obeys that again, but having no "free" left unharnessed from the first one, there will become just a wreck havoc in an extremely "over-subscribed" (  overloaded queue of tasks for so few real ( and thus by no means free in any near future ) resources to harness ) O/S's concurrency task-scheduler's scheduling attempts to map / evict / map / evict / map / evict thus more processing jobs on the same real ( and already pretty busy ) hardware elements ).

Often even the first attempt may create troubles on the RAM-allocations side, as large models will require that many replications in all the RAM-data-structures during the process instantiations ( a whole copy is effectively made with all objects, used or not used, replicated into each new process ), as the number of CPU-cores "dictates". Resulting memory swaps are definitely a thing you will never like to repeat.

Enjoy the model HyperParameters' tuning - it is the Creame a la Creame of the Machine Learning practice. Worth being good at.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's still not clear to me if there would be any difference by allocating the workers between `RandomizedSearchCV()` and `XGBClassifier()` in different proportions. Unfortunately I cannot run this test now, but even the intuition behing it would be appreciated.

Comment: Always welcome, @Alessandro the whole point is, given your code insists to use all, indeed all resources for processing task-A, there will be no resources free for working on task-B. Analogy is, using a split of resources makes no sense for reserving a part of the resources for a task-B ( searching ), given the task-B depends on having completed task-A ( the learner's completed .fit()-phase ). So there is again no benefit from reducing resources for first completing the task-A ( the .fit() performed ASAP, as one cannot test it in the "outer" *CV()-test sooner than once the .fit() is complete )